# Avoid FK creation on Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We are working on a new project using .net core and Entity Framework core, but the database is pre-existent. The database has a few glitches, but to avoid introducing any error we are trying to not alter any of its objects nor creating new ones. Right now there is a master table that has two child tables, but there is no Foreign Key from the children to the master. I added navigation properties and the SQL gets generated just fine. However, if I want to create a new migration for a different thing, I see the FKs (and indexes) get generated. Since the code works even without the FKs, can I tell EF not to generate them?

Comment: if you don't want FK's, remove the navigation property, as it most likely cannot be filled correctly anyways, or configure the relationship as a 1-to-1

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, the relations are 1 to many. Also, I need the property to exist as EF will store the data on the child entities, which is actually working right now, even with no FK existing in the database. My problem is, when I create a migration for a different matter, a script for adding the FKs is stuffed in there too

Comment: I can't imagine how you would establish a one-to-many relationship without FK. Is it some sort of inheritance? Would you show your classes and db schema?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I just have two different classes, and class A has a ```ICollection``` of class B, and class B has a property that is a single instance of class A. Both properties have the attribute ```InverseProperty```. This works fine even with the database lacking the FK.

Comment: what was the matching db schema then? I do not know of a way to establish a one-to-many relationship without the use of FK's.